# React-Anchor-Link-Smooth-Scroll not scrolling to anchored ID's

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

As the title states. My current code looks like this (code reduced for readability):

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import styles from './SideNav.module.scss'
import {useTrail, animated} from 'react-spring'
import {useInView} from 'react-intersection-observer'
import AnchorLink from 'react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll'


const SideNav = () => {

    const navItems = ['Skillset', 'Projects', 'Contact']
    const [ref, inView] = useInView({
        threshold: 1
    })

    const trail = useTrail(navItems.length, {
        to: {
            opacity: inView ? 1: 0,
            transform: inView ? `translate(0px)` : `translate(-120px)`,
        },
        from: {
            opacity: 0,
            transform: `translate(-120px)`
        },
    })
    return(
        <>
        <div className={styles.sideNav}>
            <div className={styles.navElements}>
                <section className={styles.brand}>
                    <h1 className={styles.name}>Josh Bangle</h1>
                    <h3>Web Dev. Voice Actor. Dad. Nerd.</h3>              
                </section>
                <ul ref={ref} className={styles.navList}>
                    {trail.map((props, i) => (
                        <animated.li style={props} key={i}>
                            <AnchorLink href={`#${navItems[i].toLowerCase()}`} className={styles.sideLink}>{navItems[i]} </AnchorLink>                   
                        </animated.li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default SideNav
```

It may be a bit messy, but it dynamically creates the nav links with the trail animation, and I'm using the react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll package to reach out to my corresponding components. In my Contact component, I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'




const Contact = () => {
    return (
        <section id='contact'>
            <h2>test</h2>
            <ContactContent>
                <Headline>Contact me</Headline>
                <h1>Feel free to reach out to me through LinkedIn, or email me directly at:</h1>
                <Email>joshua.bangle@gmail.com</Email>
            </ContactContent>
        </section>
    );
}

export default Contact;
```

The contact ID, which the contact anchor link has as its `href`, is set to the section element. This element even appears in the DOM source when inspected. Yet the Anchor link is not scrolling to the contact page on my app. Is there any obvious error in my implementation of the anchor link that I'm missing?

Comment: I haven't used this library, but why is the ```href``` preceded by "pathLink?" Shouldn't it just be the ID of the anchor element?

Comment: Ahh that was left in there from a previous library called hash-link or something along those lines, meant to accomplish the same task but had the side effect of polluting the url with the hash link. Removed from the code, but still no working anchor links. Generic <a> tags work as expected with anchors, but i'm hoping for the library functionality of having a simple active prop for applying active styles instead of creating that myself. Though I may just have to.